# how to access Vuex store from Axios config file?

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, vue-composition-api

I'm using Vue 3 composition and Vuex

this is axios config file

**http.js**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import  useStore  from "@/stores/index.js";
const store = useStore()

const http = axios.create({
    //from env
    baseURL: "https://challenge.spexa.dev/"  
  })

http.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    
    console.log("store" + store) // return undefined
    const token = store.getters['token']
  
    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
    return config;
  });
  
  
  export default  http
```

the problem is that store **works** fine inside component **But** not in axios config module and I cant access it (!!!?) .

and this is store
**store/index.js**

```js
import Vuex from "vuex";
import http from "../services/http";

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    access_token: null,
    refresh_token: null,
  },

  getters: {
    token(state) {
      return state.access_token
    }
  },

});
```

and this is **main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from './stores/index';
import App from './App.vue'
  
createApp(App).use(store).mount('#app')
```

so ,what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> so ,what's the problem ?

well, hard to tell without seeing what `useStore from "@/stores/index.js"` is doing.

> store **works** fine inside component **But** not in axios config module

Is not a lot to go one and you may need to define what "not" working means. Is `sotre` undefined or is the value not staying reactive?

Maybe you meant to do this ‍♂️:

```js
import { store } from "@/stores/index.js";
```

instead of"

```js
import  useStore  from "@/stores/index.js";
const store = useStore()
```